# Ambiguous match error when calling overloaded .asmx methods dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, dynamic, asmx

I am using reflection and WSDL to call web services on the fly through dynamically constructed proxy classes, and I have just added some overloaded web methods to one of the web services I am calling. Now I get an 'Ambigious match' error when trying to Invoke (via reflection) the method.

Here is the class that builds the service proxy and has a method to invoke any given web method in that proxy by name:

```
public class ServiceProxy
{
    public ServiceMetadata Metadata { get; private set; }

    public RemoteServiceElement Element { get; private set; } 

    public string IpAddress { get; private set; } 

    private object serviceProxy;
    private string serviceAsmx;

    public ServiceProxy(RemoteServiceElement element)
    {
        IpAddress = element.IpAddress;
        Element = element; 

        serviceAsmx = "http://" + element.IpAddress + ":" + element.Port     + "xxxx.asmx"            
        Build(serviceAsmx, "xxxx"); 
    }

    public ServiceProxy(string ip, string _asmx, string _serviceName)
    {
        IpAddress = ip; 

        serviceAsmx = _asmx;
        Build(_asmx, _serviceName);
    }

    private void Build(string webServiceAsmx, string serviceName)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        Metadata = ServiceMetadata.OpenWsdl(webServiceAsmx);

        Stream stream = client.OpenRead(webServiceAsmx + "?wsdl");
        ServiceDescription description = ServiceDescription.Read(stream);
        ServiceDescriptionImporter importer = new ServiceDescriptionImporter();

        importer.ProtocolName = "Soap12";
        importer.AddServiceDescription(description, null, null);
        importer.Style = ServiceDescriptionImportStyle.Client;
        importer.CodeGenerationOptions = CodeGenerationOptions.GenerateProperties;

        CodeNamespace nmspace = new CodeNamespace();
        CodeCompileUnit unit1 = new CodeCompileUnit();

        unit1.Namespaces.Add(nmspace);

        ServiceDescriptionImportWarnings warning = importer.Import(nmspace, unit1);

        if (warning == 0)
        {
            CodeDomProvider provider1 = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");

            string[] assemblyReferences = new string[5] { "System.dll", "System.Web.Services.dll", "System.Web.dll",
                "System.Xml.dll","System.Data.dll"  };

            CompilerParameters param = new CompilerParameters(assemblyReferences);
            CompilerResults results = provider1.CompileAssemblyFromDom(param, unit1);

            if (results.Errors.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (CompilerError err in results.Errors)
                {
                    Logger.Write("Compiler error assembling " + webServiceAsmx + " - " + err.ErrorText);
                }
                throw new Exception("Compiler error occurred calling the web service. Check log for details.");
            }

            serviceProxy = results.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance(serviceName);
            Logger.Write("Proxy service at + " + serviceAsmx + " assembled successfully"); 
        }

    }

    public object Invoke(string methodName, object[] args = null)
    {
        MethodInfo info = serviceProxy.GetType().GetMethod(methodName);

        object asmxResults = default(object);

        try
        {
            asmxResults = info.Invoke(serviceProxy, args);
            Logger.Write("Remote proxy at " + serviceAsmx + " - " + methodName + " - " + "invoked successfully"); 
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.Write("Error invoking proxy class at " + serviceAsmx + " - " + e.InnerException);
        }

        return asmxResults;
    }
}
```

This worked fine before I added any overloads. So I am guessing that using reflection + overloads may be causing an issue.

Here is a mock-up example of one of the WebMethods that causes the problem:

```
    [WebMethod (MessageName="GetFoos")]
    public List<Foo> GetFoos(DateTime dt)
    {
        // performs linq query
    }

    [WebMethod (MessageName = "GetFoosDynamic")]
    public List<Foo> GetFoos(Expression exp)
    {
        // linq query
    }
```

Same method name, different parameters + different 'MessageName' which is supposed to work for web services.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You are not showing how `ServiceProxy.Invoke` is being called. `.Invoke("GetFoosDynamic")`? `.Invoke("GetFoos")`?

Comment: Its being called by the method name - "GetFoos", not the MessageName. Should it be called by MessageName?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOAP doesn't support method overloading, but it looks like you've overridden your method name with the `WebMethod` attribute, so you should be calling the names you've defined within that attribute when you make your SOAP call.

Comment: So effectively overloading won't work then, right? I have to call by the MessageName attribute rather than the name of the method .

Comment: Correct, the default convention in ASMX is that the method name is the MessageName, unless you've explicitly defined a MessageName, as you have in your code.

Comment: can you please sheared me the code, how you call MessageName instead of method name

Comment: From the client, you do not have any control over calling by method name instead of MessageName. Think of it as a convention. If you have not explicitly defined a MessageName for your public method, then at runtime, the MessageName _IS_ the method name. Here's a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soaphttpclientprotocol.invoke.aspx) to MSDN that describes how to make calls to a SOAP service. You should only need to do this if you are making dynamic calls, otherwise, use the wsdl.exe tool to generate a proxy service class for you.